# About char b prefix in Python3.4.1 client connect to redis

Tags: python, redis

I am run into trouble .My code below.But I do not know why there is a char 'b' before output string "Hello Python".

```
>>> import redis
>>> redisClient = redis.StrictRedis(host='192.168.3.88',port=6379)
>>> redisClient.set('test_redis', 'Hello Python')
True
>>> value = redisClient.get('test_redis')
>>> print(value)
b'Hello Python' //why char 'b' output?
```

Answer (score 60, accepted):

`b'Hello Python'` is a byte string - redis will auto-encode a unicode string for you on the way in, but it's your job to decode it on the way out.

Better to explicitly encode and decode:

```
>>> redisClient.set('test_redis', 'Hello Python'.encode('utf-8'))
>>> redisClient.get('test_redis').decode('utf-8')
'Hello Python'
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this...but does it seem logically correct that it will auto-encode on its own will and but decode only if you say it to..I mean does not seem more of a self biased way of getting things done.

Comment: @sidd.rc: One of the key ideas in python 3 is that encoding/decoding is never automatic. auto-encoding here is very bad, because you can't decode it unless you know which encoding was used.

Comment: @Eric ok thank you for this :) , I am new to python myself . Much thanks for adding to my knowledge

Answer (score 103):

It means it's a byte string

You can use:

```
redis.StrictRedis(host="localhost", port=6379, charset="utf-8", decode_responses=True)
```

using `decode_responses=True` to make a unicode string.

Comment: Note that this prevents you from storing true binary data in your database, as it will be incorrectly treated as UTF8-encoded strings

Comment: Odd how `decode_responses` is left undescribed in [the docs](http://redis-py.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#redis.StrictRedis)

Comment: @Eric the defination is `class redis.StrictRedis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0, password=None, socket_timeout=None, connection_pool=None, charset='utf-8', errors='strict', decode_responses=False, unix_socket_path=None)` , `decode_responses=False` is default.

Comment: What does the `port=6379` parameter do?

Comment: @CaptRisky, obviously. But why should I care which port is being used; it seems to work fine when I leave out this arg? I checked the redis-py docs and didn't find anything about this.

Comment: If it's omitted, it uses the default port for redis, if you configured redis for a different port, you would require this parameter

Comment: Thanks. I used `redis_db = redis.Redis(host='localhost', port=6379, db='12',decode_responses=True, charset='utf-8')`, and worked.

Comment: @Eric: true binary data can still be stored (and will be so correctly); in order to retrieve such binary data, another client needs to be used. I proposed something like that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63164404/758174).