# Python redis returns results with appended text to result

Tags: python, redis

I just started to use redis with python, from command line and in jupyter notebooks and i get appended text to both places. code is as follows:

```
import redis
r = redis.StrictRedis(host='123.456.789.123', port=6379, db=0, password='mypwd')

r.hmset('hmfoo', { 'name': 'myname', 'username': 'myusername'})
True

r.hget('hmfoo', 'name')
b'myname' <----- why is the 'b' appended here??
```

it works as you expect with the right values stored in redis and everything, just not sure why the b is showing at the start of the text

Comment: great link, also this one gave me the clear answer i needed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25745053/about-char-b-prefix-in-python3-4-1-client-connect-to-redis

Answer (score 1):

it turns out its not a string but a byte string result and the 'b' is to indicate that. You can learn more about it from the link provided by armnotstrong [What does the 'b' character do in front of a string literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269765/what-does-the-b-character-do-in-front-of-a-string-literal)

but i found the answer in this SO post
[About char b prefix in Python3.4.1 client connect to redis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25745053/about-char-b-prefix-in-python3-4-1-client-connect-to-redis)

to get the result as a string you have 2 options:

**1.** set the encoding in the connection (charset='utf-8', decode_responses=True)

or

**2.** decode the result to convert to a string for example
r.get('foo').decode('utf-8')