# How to grab key from Redis

Tags: python, database, redis

Code

```
import redis
r = redis.StrictRedis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)

test = r.get("Name")

print (test)
```

Im trying to Print the value inside of "Name"

Manually Getting Key "Name"

```
root@Vibs:~# redis-cli
127.0.0.1:6379> get Name
"Joel"
```

When I Execute The Code

```
root@Vibs:~# python3 test.py
b'Joel'
```

Trying to create a database that can be set from a HTML form, then sent into variables in a python script to run on a bot for discord.

Comment: try this code to gt all keys: for key in r.scan_iter("user:*"):

Comment: i got it to print the value for the key, but for some reason theres a "b" in front of the output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your call to setup the Redis connection from:

```
r = redis.StrictRedis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)
```

to:

```
r = redis.StrictRedis('localhost', 6379, charset='utf-8', decode_responses=True)
```

The `decode_responses` flag tells the client to auto-convert the values from binary to a Python String.  The charset indicates which charset should be used for the conversion.

More information can be found here: [About char b prefix in Python3.4.1 client connect to redis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25745053/about-char-b-prefix-in-python3-4-1-client-connect-to-redis)